# Term for "globally analytic" functions?

Tags: terminology, analytic-functions

An analytic function $f$ is a function that is **locally** given by a convergent power series: for each $x_0$, there is a neighborhood within which the taylor series around $x_0$ equals $f$.

But for some analytic functions, the neighborhood around which this is true is the function's entire domain. E.g. the exponential function.

Is there a name for such "**globally**" analytic functions?

Comment: Restrictions to $\mathbb{R}$ of entire functions?